# cannot convert from "System.IO.FileInfo" to string

Tags: c#

```
  public class program
  {  
        private static void Main()
                {
                    string table = "T_CONSIGNACION";
                    string directory = @"C:\Users\Documents\Excel"; // Put your test root here.
        
                    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                    var file= GetNewestFile(dir);
        
                    while (file!=null)
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists(file))
                        {
                            createLog("directory: " + dir + " \nfile: " + fichero + " don't exist");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            importFile(file, table);
                        }
                    }
                 
                }
        
        
        
        public static FileInfo GetNewestFile(DirectoryInfo directory)
                {
                    return directory.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .MaxBy(f => (f == null ? DateTime.MinValue : f.LastWriteTime));
                }
        
        public static void createLog(string logMessage)
                { 
                     ....... 
               }
        
         public static string importFile(string file, string table)
                {
                 ........
               }
           }
    
    public static class EnumerableMaxMinExt
        {
            public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
            {
                return source.MaxBy(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
            }
    
            public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
            {
                using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
                    }
    
                    TSource max = sourceIterator.Current;
                    TKey maxKey = selector(max);
    
                    while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
                        TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);
    
                        if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, maxKey) > 0)
                        {
                            max = candidate;
                            maxKey = candidateProjected;
                        }
                    }
    
                    return max;
                }
            }
        }
```

In the "main" i am trying to get the last updated file (excels files); in `var file` save the file and then, in the loop : if the file does not exist create a LOG, otherwise i go to import, but i get an error in the `if (!File.Exists(file))` **cannot converted from "System.IO.FileInfo" to string** and a loop occurs. I dont know if i'm doing it right. Can you help me??

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem: You have an object that is of the type `FileInfo`, but you are trying to use it as a `string`. The loop is because you have `while (file != null)`. Since you never reassign `file` in your loop, it will never stop looping.

Comment: yes, i found my bug. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File.Exists(...)` accepts a filename as a parameter, not a `FileInfo` object. Since you already have the `FileInfo`, you can just use that to see if the file exists.  It has a property `Exists`, so just use that:

```
if (!file.Exists)
```

Alternatively, if you really wanted to use `File.Exists(...)`, you can get the filename from your file info.  This is more verbose, and might be less efficient, but I present it as an option:

```
if (!File.Exists(file.FullPath))
```

As for why your loop never terminates, that is because you are never re-assigning the `file` variable. You probably need to add `file= GetNewestFile(dir);` inside the loop, but I get the feeling you have more logic errors than that. I would expect a function `GetNewestFile` to always return the same file in that directory, right?  If that is the case, it would still loop forever.

Comment: you're quite rigth, i was doing it wrong. to call the import method i have done it in the following way: ```importFile(file.Name, table);```, i didn't get an error and i think it works. what do you think?

Comment: @JerssonGA If you aren't getting errors and it appears to work, that sounds like its correct.

Answer (score 0):

looks like:

```
var file= GetNewestFile(dir);
```

returns a Fileinfo object and not a string which is what File.Exists() is expecting.
try something like:

```
!File.Exists(file.name)
```